# "Create a task..." option is not visible anymore in lightning experience

Tags: lightning-experience, tasks

Create a task option is not visible in lightning experience. Previously it was visible as per screenshot. Open Activities and Activity History related list is already available in page layouts and New Task button is also available in page layout.[image: Previous Screenshot]

[image: Now it looks like this]

Comment: Your profile have access to  quick action's task record type?

Comment: No it did not. After adding record types of task for the required profile, my problem has been resolved. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign the Record type being used by the quick action to the User's Profile.

Knowledge article - https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000340216&type=1&mode=1